# Symfony 6: How to have the index.php in the root directory?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, nginx, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Symfony application on a host, where I have no access to the webserver confinguration. Basically, I'm just able to upload the folder of the webapplication with all dependencies. So the directory structure with `public/index.php` doesnt work for me. Even a custom `.htaccess` would not work.

Following [Symfony's Guideline to override the default directory structure](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html), I copied the contents of the `public`-folder in my root directory and made the following changes:

composer.json

```
// ...
    "extra": {
        "public-dir": ".",
        // ...
    },
// ...
```

index.php

```
// ...
require_once './vendor/autoload_runtime.php';
// ...
```

But now I get a HTTP 500 Error. Is there any other way on how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: How much are you paying for the shared hosting? Its not worth the pain, also its not how Symfony is intended to be used..

Comment: I agree that changing hosts is the best approach but are you aware that Symfony has .htaccess files for Apache?  Pretty good chance it will work.  Otherwise create a new Symfony app and add one controller/template then upload it in development mode.  That should give you a better idea of what the actual errors are.  Often it's a directory permission issue.  The webserver part of the Symfony documentation will have additional things to try.

Comment: This is probably possible but if you don't have control of the DocumentRoot, then you would have to put the htaccess file in the Symfony root folder, right? If that's the case I wouldn't advise that as there has been/is known htaccess bypasses that could then expose the Symfony files..

Comment: not tested, bit might work if you add a symlink index.php pointing to `./public/index.php`